# Is it possible to get associated like 0..1 data by RIA Services?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services

I can get 1..0 data by RIA Services fine.

```
 var sFiltered = this.ObjectContext.Sequences.Include("Schedules").Include("Events")
                                    .Include("Events.EventFrames")
                                    .Include("Events.EventRules")
                                    .Include("Events.EventFrames.EventFramePlugins")
                                    .Include("Events.EventFrames.EventFramePlugins.EventFramePluginParameters")
                                    .Include("Events.EventFrames.EventFramePlugins.EventFramePluginContentItems")
                                    .Where(s => s.ID == schedule.SequenceID).FirstOrDefault();
```

So the code above works great.

The problem is that I want to get data by ClientContentItemID  [EventFramePlugins] from [ClientContentItemElements]

Please have a look at the image below. But what I don't like to do is to use 1 extra request from the WPF client to get this data. So the idea is use 1 request to get ALL data I need.

[image: DB Model]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query would return the desired result. it finally selects an anonymous type (`ClientContentItemElementId`, `Sequence`) which you can change to get the appropriate result.  However, I did not test the generated sql to see if this approach is acceptable at all.

```
sequences.Include.....Where(s => s.ID == schedule.SequenceID).SelectMany(s => s.Events).SelectMany(e => e.EventFrames).SelectMany(ef => ef.EventFramePlugins)
    .SelectMany(efp => efp.EventFramePluginContents).SelectMany(efpc => efpc.ClientContentItems).
    SelectMany(cci => cci.ClientContentItemElemts).Where(ccie => ccie.ClientContentItemElementId == myValue).
    Select(
        ccie =>
        new
            {
                ccie,
                ccie.ClientContentItem.EventFramePluginContentItem.EventFramePlugin.EventFrame.Event.
            Sequence
            });
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the clue! But with your approach I loose .Include("Events.EventRules") and I don't have "myValue" as you've suggested. I cannot use it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: Yeah you're right. Curious to see if it is at all possible to do it in one db call. If you found a solution, I'd be thankful if you share it.

Comment: Well... I decided to create some View Class in RIA Services and populate it via a classic LINQ approach.